# Chrome doesn't give me details as to why React Elements are taking a long time to render in User Timing

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, profiling

Trying to debug performance issues with my app. dev tools user Timing section won't give me any details about my react components.

I tried to follow this article to fix my react performance issues:
https://calibreapp.com/blog/react-performance-profiling-optimization/

look at the Discovering Slow function section,

see how they clicked on the pulse component and it opened up all the options at the bottom so that he was able to find the bottleneck?

mine doesn't do that. when I click on my react components that are taking a long time, nothing happens. at all.

I made sure I have source-mapping and react in developer mode. But i still get nothing. It would be awesome if I could use the dev tools to debug my performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Dev tool I like to use console.log and print currenttime in that with some uniqueue identification that which function is taking how much time etc.